# How to get value from dynamic radio button

Tags: vb.net, select, radio-button

I'm creating the 3 radio buttons in a private sub like such:

```
For counter As Integer = 0 To rc - 1

    'controller name Radio button and properties.
    Dim dynRadio As New RadioButton()
    Me.Controls.Add(dynRadio)
    With dynRadio
       .Name = CStr(ds.Tables("MakeThisNameMeaningful").Rows(counter).Item(0))
       .Location = New Point(xAxis, yAxis)
       .TabStop = False
       .Text = CStr(ds.Tables("MakeThisNameMeaningful").Rows(counter).Item(0))
       .Width = 80
    End With

    yAxis = yAxis + 40
 Next
```

The radios get drawn ok.  So I have 3 radios with the text (result of select from db) controller1, controller2, controller3

I've triead all sorts and couldnt' find anything on Google.  Oh, I should mention that I'm trying to get the radio value from another private sub.  I want to do along the lines of:

```
If controller1.Selected = true then
    'do stuff
End if
```

I know the above is wrong but not sure how to determine which radio is selected :(

Cheers,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through your radio buttons in your 2nd private sub.

```
Dim radios = Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).AsQueryable()

For Each r As RadioButton In radios
    If r.Checked Then
      'this radio is checked. do something.
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi mate, That worked a treat!!  Cheers for that.  I had no idea you could just loop through a control type.  Very nifty! (new to vb.net).